# How to use LoadKeyboardLayout in a background thread?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-layout, tthread

I'm using the [LoadKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to load and activate the keyboard layout this way:

```
procedure TfrmMain.eSearchEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadKeyboardLayout('00000429', KLF_ACTIVATE);
end;
```

It works perfectly, but it freezes the active form for 1-2 seconds, since this change takes some time. For preventing this, I've moved this code to a background thread like this:

```
type
  FLangChangeThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FLang: string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    property Lang: string read FLang write FLang;
  end;

implementation

procedure FLangChangeThread.Execute;
begin
  if FLang = 'EN' then
    LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409', KLF_ACTIVATE)
  else
  if FLang = 'FA' then
    LoadKeyboardLayout('00000429', KLF_ACTIVATE);
end;
```

This background thread I'm then running this way:

```
procedure TfrmMain.ChangeWritingLanguage(ALang: string);
begin
  with FLangChangeThread.Create(True) do
  begin
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
    Lang := ALang;
    Resume;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.eSearchEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChangeWritingLanguage('FA');
end;
```

The problem is, that it doesn't change the keyboard layout as expected.
I've debugged the code and all lines were execeuted; just the [LoadKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function hasn't made its job.

How can I make the [LoadKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function work from a background thread ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you should check the result of the [`LoadKeyboardLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and if it fails, you should check the error returned by the [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to determine what is wrong.

But even if this function call succeed, it will activate the input locale identifier, but for your worker thread. As the [`LoadKeyboardLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference states for the [`KLF_ACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#KLF_ACTIVATE) flag (emphasized by me):

> **KLF_ACTIVATE**
>
> If the specified input locale identifier is not already loaded, the
>   function loads and activates the input locale identifier **for the
>   current thread**.

---

Although, if you want to load and activate keyboard layout for the whole process, you may try to combine the [`KLF_ACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#KLF_ACTIVATE) flag with the [`KLF_SETFORPROCESS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#KLF_SETFORPROCESS) one:

```
const
  KLF_SETFORPROCESS = $00000100;
begin
  if LoadKeyboardLayout('00000429', KLF_ACTIVATE or KLF_SETFORPROCESS) = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, i should guess! how i can fix this?

Comment: I was checked the result, and it never returns NUL. how i can apply this function to active control (like a TEdit)?

Comment: If you're going to change the keyboard layout for the process (what I guess you do, the worker thread you've used since it takes a long time, don't you ?), try to combine the `KLF_ACTIVATE` flag with the `KLF_SETFORPROCESS` one.

Comment: +1. Nice answer, and nice catch of the `current thread` for `KLF_ACTIVATE`. (I must say I don't understand the poster's thought of changing the keyboard layout when entering an edit control (seems like a really bad idea to me). I know I'd quickly uninstall an app that did that.)

Comment: @TLama Yes, exactly, i want kill that 1-2sec delay time for changing keyboard layout, i want it change immediately.

Comment: @KenWhite Dear friend, I have a multilingual form that user should fill fields by different languages. the user can change language him/herself with Alt+Shift (or etc methods), but i trying to do it automatically by software when user enters a field. I want my software change input language automatically for user-friendly purposes.

Comment: @FarshadH: Thanks for the explanation. :-) I'm not sure I agree that it's user-friendly, but then I'm probably not part of your user base. <g>

Comment: @TLama Thank you for your advise, I used **KLF_SETFORPROCESS**, and it works! thanks a lot dear friend :)

Comment: @TLama Sure, I was try do it, but I'm new to http://stackoverflow.com and i need 15 reputation for this, i will do it gladly as soon as possible :)

Comment: @jachguate HiiiiHaaaaa :D u sweet :-*